# postcss-custom-properties reference vars from other files

Tags: postcss, css-variables

I have a project that is using css custom properties, defining them accross multiple files. The basic structure is one base css file has all of the generic properties defined (i.e. primary, success, etc.) with a :root selector. Then there are component level scss files that can create and use their own values (also using a :root selector) or reference the custom properties from the base file.

***base.css***

```
 :root {
      --primary: #ffffff;
 }
```

***component.css***

```
 :root {
      --componentBg: var(--primary);
 }

 .container {
      background: var(--componentBg);
 }
```

This project needs to have a fallback for browsers that do not support css custom properties, so I have attempted to integrate postcss-custom-properties into the build (webpack) following the instructions from the project. This works fine in translating var(--x) where --x is defined in the same file, however, if --x is defined in the base file, the backup property is added without fully resolving the var(--x) references.

***Output I am getting from above example:***

```
 .container {
      background: var(--primary);
      background: var(--componentBg);
 }
```

***Expected Output***

```
 .container {
      background: var(#ffffff);
      background: var(--componentBg);
 }
```

Can postcss-custom-properties be configured to reference properties defined in different files? I see there is an importFrom setting which I have tried, but I'm not exactly sure what that setting is supposed to do and there is no output in the build to let me know if it is even finding the file declared or not.